# Childrens can't get the updated Parent values

Tags: java, oop, subclass, superclass

I'm trying to create a Bank system using inheritance, the problem comes when the children BankAccount tries to retrive it's parent values, it gets the initial values of the Bank class, numberAccounts = 0 and empty registeredAccounts.

*Starts by creating 3 initial bank accounts.*

```
Bank bank = new Bank();
bank.createBankAccount("Tonny");
bank.createBankAccount("Michael");
bank.createBankAccount("Mark");
```

*Then Bank class creates and generate their giving each one's bank account and number, the current values of numberAccounts and registeredAccounts should've changed.*

```
public class Bank{
    protected BankAccount[] registeredAccounts;
    protected int numberAccounts= 0;
    private final int numberAccountAllowed = 50;
    
    public Bank() {
        registeredAccounts= new BankAccount[numberAccountAllowed];
    }

    public void createBankAccount(String name){
        int numberBankAccountGenerated;     
        if(numberAccounts >= numberAccountAllowed){
            System.out.println("Max number of bank accounts reached, can't create another one");
            return;
        }

        boolean isNumberAvailable = true;
    
        do{
            numberBankAccountGenerated = new Random().nextInt(99999 + 100000) + 100000;
        
            for(int i = 0; i < numberAccounts && isNumberAvailable; i++){
                if(numberBankAccountGenerated == registeredAccounts[i].numberAccount)
                    isNumberAvailable = false;
            }
        }while(!isNumberAvailable);
    
        registeredAccounts[numberAccounts] = new BankAccount(name, numberBankAccountGenerated);
        numberAccounts++;

        System.out.printf("A new bank account has been created with the name \"%s\" and number: #%d.\n\n", name, numberBankAccountGenerated);
    }
}
```

*When I try to call for the super class values to operate the balance transfer between accounts I realize the values are the initial of the class Bank.*

```
public class BankAccount extends Bank{
    /*
    .
    */

    public void balanceTransfer(int numberBankAccount, int amount ){
        int match = -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < super.numberAccounts && match == -1; i++)
            if(numberBankAccount == super.registeredAccounts[i].numberAccounts)
                match = i;               
    
        if(match == -1){
            System.out.println("Bank account not found.");
            return;
        }
        
        super.registeredAccounts[match].addBalance(amount);
        this.addBalance(-amount);
    }
}
```

I guess I have an execution flow problem but I can't find out the real issue with my knowlege.

Comment: I guess number accounts can be static, so that it can be used throughout classes, the number of accounts created will be then stored permanently until you rerun the activity

Comment: Inheritance indicates that instances of the subclass *are* instances of the superclass (for instance, every `String` *is* an `Object` in Java). Is it really accurate to say that every bank account *is* a bank?

Comment: I see your point, make sense, inherit such Bank methods to a Bank Account would be wrong in the given context, I thought  using this mechanism would solve my needs but now I see is bad practice

Comment: Correct. `BankAccount extends Bank` is not a proper object model.

Answer (score 1):

```
registeredAccounts[numberAccounts] = new BankAccount(name, numberBankAccountGenerated); // dumplicate another bank here
```

When you run the code as above, the obj `BankAccount` have their own value of numberAccounts, and its value is not related to the `Bank` created it.
I think you purpose was to share the value and amount in the `Bank`, it might be a way that to seperate the class `Bank` and `BankAccount`, design the way how to share those properties in `Bank`, for example, through parameters.

Comment: Well, I ended up adding getters to the Bank class to retrieve the registeredAccounts[] and the numberAccounts, also I added and extra parameter to some function passing throght them the Bank object I inital created, it worked, but I wonder if what I did is a good practice